# If rate of SN1 is more does that automatically mean rate of SN2 is less, and vice versa?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

If I have a list of compounds and I compare their S<sub>N</sub>1 reactivity, for S<sub>N</sub>2 reactivity, is it correct to use the same list but order inverted? Are there any exceptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no, it is not correct.

You can have compounds that are thermodynamically/kinetically impeded for a variety of reasons and present both slow S<sub>N</sub>1 and S<sub>N</sub>2 reactivities.

The exceptions would be carefully handcrafted “everything else being equal” lists.

Comment: Also it really depends on external factors. There is no absolute order to use.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Example 1 - neopentyl halide: slow S<sub>N</sub>2 as it has considerable steric hindrance; slow S<sub>N</sub>1 as it is a primary carbon, so it does not form stable carbocation intermediate.

Example 2 - benzyl halide: fast S<sub>N</sub>2 being a primary carbon; fast S<sub>N</sub>1 due to a resonance-stabilized benzyl carbocation intermediate.